# Converting MySQL Query to HQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have this query (It Works with MySQL):

```
Select * 
from atividade a, 
lateralidade l, 
movimento m, 
parteCorpo p, 
registroatividade r,
consulta c, 
paciente pa  
where 
    l.id_lateralidade = a.id_lateralidade 
    AND l.descricao = '?'  
    AND m.id_movimento = a.id_movimento 
    AND m.descricao = '?' 
    AND m.parteCorpo_id_parteCorpo = p.id_parteCorpo 
    AND p.descricao = '?' 
    AND r.id_atividade = a.id_atividade 
    AND a.id_planoAtividade = c.id_consulta 
    AND pa.id_paciente = c.id_paciente 
    AND pa.nome = '?';
```

I would like to convert it to HQL. So far, I have this:

```
public List<RegistroAtividade> list_regs(Atividade atividade, Paciente paciente){
Query query = this.session.createQuery("from Atividade a, Lateralidade l, Movimento m, ParteCorpo p, RegistroAtividade r,Consulta c, Paciente pa where l.id_lateralidade = a.id_lateralidade AND l.descricao = :lateralidadedesc AND m.id_movimento = a.id_movimento AND m.descricao = :movimentodesc AND m.parteCorpo_id_parteCorpo = p.id_parteCorpo AND p.descricao = :partecorpodesc AND r.id_atividade = a.id_atividade AND a.id_planoAtividade = c.id_consulta AND pa.id_paciente = c.id_paciente AND pa.nome = :pacientenome");
        query.setParameter("lateralidadedesc", atividade.getLateralidade().getDescricao());
        query.setParameter("movimentodesc", atividade.getMovimento().getDescricao());
        query.setParameter("partecorpodesc", atividade.getMovimento().getParteCorpo().getDescricao());
        query.setParameter("partecorpodesc", paciente.getNome());
        return query.list();
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: id_lateralidade of: br.com.acelerometro.entity.Atividade [select a,l,n,p,r,c,pa from br.com.acelerometro.entity.Atividade AS a, br.com.acelerometro.entity.Lateralidade AS l, br.com.acelerometro.entity.Movimento AS m, br.com.acelerometro.entity.ParteCorpo AS p, br.com.acelerometro.entity.RegistroAtividade AS r,br.com.acelerometro.entity.Consulta AS c, br.com.acelerometro.entity.Paciente AS pa where l.id_lateralidade = a.id_lateralidade AND l.descricao = :lateralidadedesc AND m.id_movimento = a.id_movimento AND m.descricao = :movimentodesc AND m.parteCorpo_id_parteCorpo = p.id_parteCorpo AND p.descricao = :partecorpodesc AND r.id_atividade = a.id_atividade AND a.id_planoAtividade = c.id_consulta AND pa.id_paciente = c.id_paciente AND pa.nome = :pacientenome]```

Comment: The joins have to be rewritten using proper HQL syntax.

Comment: Can you help me rewritten these joins?

Comment: Do you have an overwhelmingly good reason for converting a clean, legible query that works performantly into an abstracted form where you will be at the mercy of the whims of middleware that suffers from recurring pathological delusions that it is a better database than a real database?

Comment: If you have another solution than converting this query to hql, I would be glad to see it =)

Comment: @GordanBobic Hibernate is not "middleware," and that is not the OP's reason for using it.

Comment: Just like Tim said you would need to rewrite the joins and also, as the error indicates, you need to change the name of the fields i.e. `id_lateralidade` to name of properties of the classes i.e. `idLateralidade` or `id` or whatever the id is called in the class Lateralidade. It seems a quite simple query so the docs would be enough to guide you. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html If not, you should post a bit more details on the entity relations so that we could help you with the joins.

Answer (score 0):

If you using HQL then you have to used the associated property for this id_lateralidade  defined in Entity class.

Use idLateralidade  as per defined in entity
Ex :

```
public class Atividade  {

    // Field..............

     @Column(name="id_lateralidade")
     public Integer idLateralidade  

}
```